# Expo app is crashing when I do login on Production with -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbe16330273abd5a0'

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I have an Expo app with sdk 49 in a managed flow that is crashing only on a production environment on TestFlight and the Store once I do a login with this error message:

`-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbe16330273abd5a0'`

When I run the app on Expo Go or on a development build I don't get this error.

How can I debug this issue? This seems to be native code which I don't have access to it.

I am trying to reproduce this error on a dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error message [__NSCFNumber length] : unrecognised selector sent to instance 0xbe16330273abd5a0 indicates that the Expo app is trying to call a method on an object that does not exist.
2. This can happen for a number of reasons :

- A typo in the code
- A missing import statement
- A bug in the Expo app or in one of its dependencies

3. To fix this error, you will need to identify the object that the Expo app is trying to call the method on and then make sure that the object exists and that it has the method that the Expo app is trying to call.